# How do I match unenclosed spaces?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex that can match spaces as long as they occur outside of parentheses and quotes. For example, it would match the spaces after the `0`, `3`, `6`, and `9` in `0 " 1 2 "3 ( 4 5 )6 ( ( 7 ) ( "("8 ) )9 " ( A B C ) ) ( D E F ( "`.

I made a simple regex the doesn't care about parentheses:

```
\s+(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

However, I don't how to make a regex that checks for parentheses, because they can be nested.

Bonus points if it somehow checks for unmatched parentheses and quotes (in JavaScript or pseudocode).

Comment: I didn't downvote but JS regex cannot match nested parentheses

Comment: @JJY9 Does not seem to match https://regex101.com/r/f7ryyd/1

Comment: Not only are the parentheses nested but they are unbalanced, there being two more left than right. (Note that the last parenthesis in the string is a left one.) Moreover, the second right parentheses in `"...C ) ) ( D..."` matches the first left parenthesis in the string, yet it is within the clause defined by the last pair of double quotes. Is that intended?

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple parser to find the spaces (adapt for mailformed strings (no matching quotes or brackets)):

```js
const str = '0 " 1 2 "3 ( 4 5 )6 ( ( 7 ) ( "("8 ) )9 " ( A B C ) ) ( D E F ( "';

const findSpaces = (str, inside = false, from = 0, out = []) => {
    for (let i = from; i < str.length; i++) {
        const c = str[i];
        if (inside) {
            if (c === ')') return i;
        } else if (c === ' ') out.push(i);
        if (c === '"') i = str.indexOf('"', i + 1);
        else if (c === '(') i = findSpaces(str, true, i + 1);
    }
    return out;

};

console.log(findSpaces(str).map(i => `after ${str[i-1]}`));
```

```
` Cycles: 5000000 / Chrome/117
---------------------------------------------
Alexander    1.0x  |  534  543  545  551  580
3liminator   1.3x  |  718  727  735  739  751
---------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const CYCLES = 5000000;
const str = '0 " 1 2 "3 ( 4 5 )6 ( ( 7 ) ( "("8 ) )9 " ( A B C ) ) ( D E F ( "';

const findSpaces = (str, inside = false, from = 0, out = []) => {
    for (let i = from; i < str.length; i++) {
        const c = str[i];
        if (inside) {
            if (c === ')') return i;
        } else if (c === ' ') out.push(i);
        if (c === '"') i = str.indexOf('"', i + 1);
        else if (c === '(') i = findSpaces(str, true, i + 1);
    }
    return out;

};

function findSpaceIndexes(string) {
  const spaceIndexes = [];
  let   stringDepth  = 0;
  let   groupDepth   = 0;
  
  for (let index = 0; index < string.length; index += 1) {
    switch (string[index]) {
      case ' ': // store index if not inside string or group context
        if (stringDepth || groupDepth) break;
        spaceIndexes.push(index);
        break;
      case '"': // open/close string context
        stringDepth += stringDepth ? -1 : +1;
        break;
      case '(': // open group context
        if (stringDepth) break; // ignore inside string context
        groupDepth += 1;
        break;
      case ')': // close group context
        if (stringDepth) break; // ignore inside string context
        if (!groupDepth) throw new Error(`unexpected ) character at index ${index}`);
        groupDepth -= 1;
        break;
      default: // ignore 
    }
  }
  
  if (stringDepth) throw new Error('missing closing " character');
  if (groupDepth)  throw new Error(`missing ${groupDepth} closing ) character(s)`);
  
  return spaceIndexes;
}

//@benchmark 3liminator
findSpaceIndexes(str);
//@benchmark Alexander
findSpaces(str);

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Comment: This is the only way ++

Answer (score 0):

Using regex can be useful when you need to find quick patterns, but whenever things get more complex and you need to keep track of nesting a JavaScript regex cannot help you any longer. So you'll have to parse your string.

Here is a fairly simple example parser using a `switch` statement.

Note that though this fits the example scenario given, it is intended as inspiration. The given string is probably not your actual scenario, so you probably need to tweak the code.

```js
function findSpaceIndexes(string) {
  const spaceIndexes = [];
  let   stringDepth  = 0;
  let   groupDepth   = 0;
  
  for (let index = 0; index < string.length; index += 1) {
    switch (string[index]) {
      case ' ': // store index if not inside string or group context
        if (stringDepth || groupDepth) break;
        spaceIndexes.push(index);
        break;
      case '"': // open/close string context
        stringDepth += stringDepth ? -1 : +1;
        break;
      case '(': // open group context
        if (stringDepth) break; // ignore inside string context
        groupDepth += 1;
        break;
      case ')': // close group context
        if (stringDepth) break; // ignore inside string context
        if (!groupDepth) throw new Error(`unexpected ) character at index ${index}`);
        groupDepth -= 1;
        break;
      default: // ignore 
    }
  }
  
  if (stringDepth) throw new Error('missing closing " character');
  if (groupDepth)  throw new Error(`missing ${groupDepth} closing ) character(s)`);
  
  return spaceIndexes;
}

const str = '0 " 1 2 "3 ( 4 5 )6 ( ( 7 ) ( "("8 ) )9 " ( A B C ) ) ( D E F ( "';
//            ^-1      ^-10     ^-19                ^-39
console.log(findSpaceIndexes(str));
```

To allow backslash escaping within strings, add the following code as first `case`:

```
case '\\': // allow backslash escaping of any character in string context
  if (stringDepth) {
    index += 1;
    break;
  }
  // fall through if not in string context
```

I'm not sure whatever you intent to do with the found spaces, but say you want to replace them with underscores you can do so with the following code:

```
const str = '0 " 1 2 "3 ( 4 5 )6 ( ( 7 ) ( "("8 ) )9 " ( A B C ) ) ( D E F ( "';
const spaceIndexes = findSpaceIndexes(str);
spaceIndexes.reverse();
const newStr = spaceIndexes.reduce((str, index) => (
  str.slice(0, index) + "_" + str.slice(index + 1)
), str);
console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

As JavaScript regexes don't support recursion (yet), you'll need some JavaScript code to parse the input.

Here is an iterative solution with `depth` reflecting the nesting of parentheses:

```js
function findOuterSpaces(str) {
    let depth = 0;
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        const ch = str[i];
        if (ch === ' ') { 
            if (!depth) result.push(i);
        } else if (ch === '"') {
            i = str.indexOf('"', i + 1);
            if (i < 0) throw Error("Unbalanced quotes");
        } else if (ch === '(') {
            depth++;
        } else if (ch === ')') {
            if (!depth--) throw Error("Too many closing parentheses");
        }
    }
    if (depth) throw Error("Too few closing parentheses");
    return result;
}

const test = '0 " 1 2 "3 ( 4 5 )6 ( ( 7 ) ( "("8 ) )9 " ( A B C ) ) ( D E F ( ".';
console.log("indexes:", ...findOuterSpaces(test));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really select not`%a` in regex, you'll have to `(?:%a)%b` to find not`%a` or `(%a)(%b)`->`$1%c` to replace not`%a`

Anyways, here's how to define your `%B`="parentheses and quotes" and `%0` to search for

```
// skip string/bracket/deep-bracket -s, pick space
%0 = (?:%s|%b|%B|\S)*(\s)
// char:
%c = [^"()]
// string:
%s = "[^"]*"
// brackets:
%b = \((?:%c|%s)*\)
// brackets-in-brackets:
%B = \((?:%c|%s|%b)*\)
```

resulting in regex of https://regex101.com/r/ffhCQg/1

```
/(?:"[^"]*"|\((?:[^"()]|"[^"]*")*\)|\((?:[^"()]|"[^"]*"|\((?:[^"()]|"[^"]*")*\))*\)|\S)*(\s)/g
```

[image]

---

If you want a script I've used to use the above markup language on regex101.com, it's https://tsplay.dev/dimava-regex101-markup-1